# No accessor method and mutator method

Tags: java

I was told by my lecturer that i have no accessor and mutator method in my class,but i have no idea what he means as i did include my accessor and mutator methods.

The 2 issue i can come up with are:

1.My mutator have to be for each individual variable instead of all the variable at once.

2.My sub-class needs accessor and mutator method for my super class variables.

I did ask my lecture but he said go figure it out yourself, and i didn't include the toString

```
        abstract class TwoD implements Shape
{
    //protected instance variables as the subclasses will use them
    protected int a;
    protected int b;
    protected int c;

    //default constructor
    public TwoD() {}

    //constructor for circle
    public TwoD(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    //constructor for rectangle
    public TwoD(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    //constructor for triangle
    public TwoD(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b; 
        this.c = c;
    }

    //copy constructor
    public TwoD(TwoD td)
    {
        this (td.a, td.b, td.c);
    }

    //accessor methods to get variables
    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    //mutator methods to set variables
    public void setA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setAB(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void setABC(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
class Circle extends TwoD
{
    //default constructor
    public Circle() {}

    public Circle(int radius)
    {
        super(radius);
    }

    //method to calculate area of circle
    @Override
    public double area()
    {
        return Math.PI * a * a;
    }

    //method to get calculated area
    @Override
    public double getArea()
    {
        return area();
    }
```

Comment: You have figured it out yourself. Your lecturer meant what you describe in point 1 and 2. All you need to do is get rid of `setAB` and `setABC` and add the setter methods. (The words 'accessor' and 'mutator' are synonymous to getter and setter respectively.)

Comment: So i still need accessor and mutator method for my subclass even though i already did it in my super class? From my understanding is that i already have a get and set method for variables a,b and c in my TwoD super class.
There is no reason for me to add another get and set method for the same variables in my Circle subclass.

Comment: That's not necessary, because `Circle` extends all non-private non-static methods from `TwoD`.

Comment: I'd recommend you make the variable fields be private as well. There is no need to give direct access to them for the sub classes since they can call the getter and setter methods and it would make it harder to change behavior in the future if you don't.

Comment: @AaronDavis Normally i would but i'm currently following a uml diagram by my lecturer.

Comment: @MCEmperor okay thanks i get it now.

Comment: @KevinChee It's also a bit weird that the `Shape` interface defines both `area()` as `getArea()`. Both methods seem to do the same.

Comment: It might be defined in your school work to use this class at all, but I honestly don't love the design of the super class. It appears to be used by different sub classes in different ways but will be exposing methods that don't really make sense to the concrete sub class.

Comment: . For example, the following code is valid:
```
Circle circle = new Circle(10);
circle.getArea();
// those above totally make sense, however, the following
// ones are also visible methods on the Circle class and don't
// make sense for a "circle" object
circle.getA();
circle.getB();
circle.getC();
circle.setA(1);
circle.setB(2);
circle.setC(3);
```

Comment: Thank you , this really cleared up a lot of confusion regarding the Assignment I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessor methods are often called getters and mutator methods are often called setters.

A widely used pattern within the Java world is that you

- make your fields (instance variables) private

  ```
  private int a;
  ```
- add a getter if you need an accessor method

  ```
  public int getA() {
      return this.a;
  }
  ```
- add a setter if you need a mutator method

  ```
  public void setA(int a) {
      this.a = a;
  }
  ```

Accessor and mutator methods almost always change **a single field**.

Note that I, [just like Aaron Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011421/no-accessor-method-and-mutator-method/53011702#comment92926733_53011421), don't like this design either. Since subclasses are only able to add functionality, and are unable to remove or hide it, one must choose wisely which class extends the other. An example would be the well-known [squares-rectangles problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set).

---

You also need to use self-descriptive names. `a`, `b` and `c` should be renamed to something better describing what those variables represent.